# How to tell if html element is manually selected or default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a set of options can I determine if the currently selected value is manually set vs defaulting using only javascript (I can't modify the html since I'm using build in framework functionality).

```
<select>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
<select>
```

should be distinguishable from

```
<select>
    <option value="a" selected="selected">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
<select>
```

Even though both will have A selected.

Javascript will run on page load. I need to tell if html was sent from server with selected and if not then set the selectedIndex = -1

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? The solution becomes quite obvious if you look into it.

Comment: You could check to see if the attribute `selected` exists for that particular element in a `for-each` loop that loops on your select. You'll need to give it an ID though for that to work.

Comment: @ScottMcGready How does that help? What if the user manually selects the default option? The attribute will exist.

Comment: @Baramar Perhaps then instead of defaulting to "a" it should have a "Please Select" option.

Comment: He said he can't change the HTML

Comment: Bind a `change` handler to tell when the user manually changes the option.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things. $($('.select-minus-one :selected')[0]).attr('selected') will always be true. I can't seem to distinguish. @ScottMcGready - I am using a framework I can't do that

Comment: @Nit - please put obvious solution below

Comment: @Barmar I totally missed that. Well in this case, do the check to see if `selected` exists and if it doesn't I think it's fair to assume that `a` has been selected.

Comment: Looking at the `HTMLOptionElement` API, it really seems like the only way to find out whether the user made a selection is to bind a `change` event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling - this javascript will be run on document ready. I need to tell if the html came over with a selected and if not then set selectedIndex -1

Comment: @matthewdaniel: Well, then it's easy. As already said, check whether the `selected` attribute exist on any of the options. Or just do `$('select').get(0).selectedIndex === -1`.

Comment: @FelixKling - how? the jquery in a comment above can't seem to differentiate

Comment: E.g. `$('select option[selected]').length === 0` or `$('select').val() === ''` or `$('select').get(0).selectedIndex === -1` or something similar.

Comment: @FelixKling - there we go, it seems that option[selected] is very different from :selected. I think that might work

Comment: `$('select :selected').length === 0` should work too.

Comment: @FelixKling if you want to post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: \*cough\* there is a world beyond the comments section...

Answer (score 1):

Using the `onchange` event we can just flag that the user has selected it.

```
var selection = document.getElementById('selection');

selection.onchange = function(){

  user_selected = true;

}
```

With some markup like this:

```
<select id="selection">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
<select>
```

*Here's a [fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/26zuB/2/)*

Answer (score 0):

try working an if statement into this for your value to match the selection...also, there are super easy jquery options...if you can use jquery.

```
  
<script>  
var selectedOption = document.getElementsByTagName("select");  
if (!selectedOption.options[selectedOption.selectedIndex].defaultSelected) alert("select has changed");  
</script>
```